# Unable to find contextual data of type: java.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequest (Wildfly error)

Tags: jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

I am using wildfly 9.0.1.Final

I am deploying a REST application which has an endpoint defined like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/view/products")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@CORSEnabled
@Protected
public String getConfiguredProducts(
    @Context ContainerRequestContext request) {
    if (request != null) {
        Integer companyId = (Integer) request.getProperty("company");
        if (companyId != null) {
             //do stuff
        }
    }
    // ... more staff
}
```

When the application runs, the context is injected, i.e. 'request' is non null.

When I try though to retrieve the property I get back the error:

```
executing GET /complaints/view/products:        
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.LoggableFailure: Unable to find contextual data    
of type: javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext
```

Please note that the application was running without problems on glassfish/jersey and the problem appeared when I tried to move it to wildfly/resteasy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am answering my own question, since it seems that RestEasy does not support injection of a ContainerRequestContext, at least according to this

https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html_single/#_Context

> The @Context annotation allows you to inject instances of 
>   javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders, javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo, 
>   javax.ws.rs.core.Request, javax.servlet.HttpServletRequest, 
>   javax.servlet.HttpServletResponse, javax.servlet.ServletConfig, 
>   javax.servlet.ServletContext, and javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext
>   objects.

I injected a javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders instead, where I had previously added all the information I needed.

Answer (score 9):

I also had the error
`RESTEASY003880: Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders`

It was caused by accessing the headers in a different thread.

Hopefully the answer will help when googling the problem.

Comment: in my case i have to extract all multiform data and store that in local variable and pass those variable to new thread.If i pass multifom data to new thread directly i was getting this error

Comment: So for `@Context private javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders headers;` , it can't be shared by multiple threads? What's the reason for that? If it is readonly headers, I can't see why it can't be shared.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was simply an invalid Content-Type header.  Error certainly was misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I was just interested in the `SecurityContext` object (which is previously added in a `ContainerRequestFilter` using `requestContext.setSecurityContext`)

RestEasy can directly inject this `SecurityContext` object:

```
@POST
@Path("/x")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response x(
            final @Context SecurityContext securityContext) {
}
```