# Override REST POST method based on type of request

Tags: web-services, jax-rs, resteasy

I am using resteasy and I want to have two post methods like this -

```
@POST    
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public void post(   @PathParam("p1") String p1, 
                        @PathParam("p2") String p2,
                        @PathParam("p3") String p3,
                        @Suspended AsyncResponse asyncResponse, 
                        @Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                        MultipartFormDataInput input)
@POST    
public void post(   @PathParam("p1") String p1, 
                            @PathParam("p2") String p2,
                            @PathParam("p3") String p3,
                            @Suspended AsyncResponse asyncResponse, 
                            @Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest)
```

First post method to handle file  uploads and other post method to handle all requests except file uploads. But when I test these methods, file upload works fine but requests other than file upload do not reach any of these methods. How can I achieve this?
Also, I am fine if I can somehow receive both types of requests in a single method and then handle the requests conditionally based on whether file was uploaded or not...

Comment: hey there, would you be willing to show me what your client code looks like? I keep getting the error `Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers`, and injecting the `@Context Providers providers` as a parameter doesn't help :(   Thank you

Comment: Sorry buddy... Now I don't have this code..

Comment: Probably this would help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32436419/unable-to-find-contextual-data-of-type-java-ws-rs-container-containerrequest-w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh..Sorry guys.. Must be a build issue because the above method signatures are working fine.. :)

Comment: Did the first method got called when there is a file upload? Also, did it call the second method when there is no file upload?